# crear una tabla de amortización en C#

Tags: c#

> Desarrolle un programa que permita saber la cuota de préstamo que pagará una
> persona tomando en cuenta el monto, tasa de interés y el tiempo, para ello, deberá
> investigar el calculo de una cuota de préstamo a pagar. Mostrar como resultado en
> pantalla, el monto de préstamo, la tasa, el tiempo y la cuota a pagar.

> Partiendo del ejercicio sobre la cuota de préstamo, debe agregar
> funcionalidades de que el programa al momento de determinar la cantidad de
> cuotas, muestre en pantalla una tabla de amortización, la cual contiene el
> numero de la cuota, cuota, interés, capital y el balance, hasta quedar en cero (0),
> para esto, debe investigar sobre tabla de amortización sobre un préstamo.

este es el código del préstamo que he desarrollado:

```
using System;

namespace prestamo_01
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            recopilar informacion

            Console.WriteLine("ingrese el monto solicitado");
            double Prestamo = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("ingrese el porcentaje de interes ");
            double interes = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("ingrese plazo en meses a pagar");
            int Tiempo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //aqui hago los calculos
            interes = (Prestamo * interes) / 100;

            double PrestamoTotal = Prestamo + interes;

            double Cuotas = PrestamoTotal / Tiempo;
            //ahora muestro lo pedido en pantalla

            Console.WriteLine("el monto del prestamo es de: " + PrestamoTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("la tasa a pagar es de: " + interes);
            Console.WriteLine("el tiempo a pagar es de: " + Tiempo);
            Console.WriteLine("la cuota mensual es de: " + Cuotas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y qué problema tienes con lo que has hecho ?

Comment: calcular el préstamo esta bien pero no entiendo como hacer la tabla de amortización

Comment: No entiendes como programarla o cómo se calcula?

Comment: entiendo mas o menos como calcularlo pero nada la programación

Comment: Entiendo. El primer paso para resolverlo es que primero entiendas a la perfección como calcularlo. Luego de tener esa claridad ya puedes intentar hacer código, sentarse a programar sin entender lo que se quiere programar solo es una pérdida de tiempo ( es un consejo ). Te explico eso porque en este sitio la ayuda es con problemas puntuales de programación de manera que tu pregunta debe incluir la explicación de cómo se calcula la tabla de amortización y también el código que has intentado y que no logras hacer funcionar y así se te puede ayudar a adaptar la lógica necesaria.